# Calculating prime factor error

Tags: c, variables, prime-factoring

This is not a copy thread because i am not asking how i can calculate prime factors of a number. I have a problem in the code and any thread title suggestions are welcome.

So my code works for numbers up to billions. But even though i am using long(64 bit), instead of giving my prime factors after a time of calculation, my code works instantly(when i give it a huge number) and it says no prime factors found.(you can run the code to see what i am talking about)

edit: I was using 32 bit variables that was the problem. I changed to long long from long. And now it works but its very very slow for big inputs.

edit2: I was keeping prime factors in an array and it had an extremely long time to work for big numbers(5 billion+). When i stopped using arrays and simply printed the results i worked much much faster. Still work slow if you test your computers limits. No matter how good your order of growth is if you enter a big enough input you will sweat your cpu. Great example of how tiny C(op) can effect your algorithfor huge C(n) values.

edit3: This algorithm doesnt work for prime numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

long long number, halfTheNumber, arrayCounter = 0, primeNumberCounter = 2;
long long array1[100] = {0};

printf("Enter number to find its prime factors: ");
scanf("%llu", &number);

halfTheNumber = number / 2;
for(; primeNumberCounter <= halfTheNumber; primeNumberCounter++)
{
    while(number % primeNumberCounter == 0 && number > 1)
    {
        number /= primeNumberCounter;
        array1[arrayCounter] = primeNumberCounter;
        arrayCounter++;
    }
}

for(arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter <= 99; arrayCounter++)
{
    printf("\n%lu. prime factor: %llu", arrayCounter, array1[arrayCounter]);
}

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the size of long in your system? What input are you giving?

Comment: @GoodDeeds 64 bit. So -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to                    -9,223,372,036,854,775,807. I am giving different inputs. Small numbers work. But when i go above billions it starts not working.

Comment: Could you give a sample input with the output?

Comment: When you step through with a debugger, where does it fail? If you haven't stepped through your code line-by-line with a debugger yet, you really, really should learn to do so, since it's pretty much required knowledge for virtually every programmer.

Comment: Interesting... I could swear i tested range of long a few days ago and it was not 32 bits... I just checked and it is 32 bits guys. Weird.

Comment: If you want at least 64 bits, don't use `long`, but `long long` (better: `unsigned long long`).

Comment: In 32-bit code, `long` is always 32 bits. In 64-bit code, it depends on whether you are using Windows or Linux. On Windows, `long` is still 32 bits. On Linux, `long` is 64 bits. If you want to guarantee a 64-bit type, use `long long`. Or better yet, include `stdint.h` and use `int64_t`.

Comment: @CodyGray i just created an unsigned long long and assigned 0 to it. then subtracted 1 from it and result was 4 billion. So i am guessing its 32 bit too.

Comment: @madkobra You probably made a mistake, then.  I can just about guarantee you that `unsigned long long` is 64 bits.  (And it's *definitely* not 32 bits.)

Comment: @SteveSummit You are right. I used a wrong format specifier. Now my code works but its extremely slow for big inputs since its brute force.

Comment: Whenever you divide `number` by a prime factor you've just found, recompute `halfTheNumber`.  That'll speed it up a lot.  Next, use `sqrt()` instead of dividing by 2.  That'll speed it up some more.

Comment: @SteveSummit take square root of what instead of diving?

Comment: Instead of computing `halfTheNumber = number / 2`, you can use some variation on `halfTheNumber = sqrt(number)`.  (But now there's `<math.h>` and some floating point involved.)

Comment: After your edits that made the problem go away, there is nothing left to ask, right?

Comment: @RadLexus just realised this algorithm doesnt work for prime numbers since we are dividing the number as we go in order to make the algorithm faster.